# iterate array's each object and add value in new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Kindly check json and expected output if you didn't get what I am asking.

```
"arrayData" = [{
        "id": "string",
        "label": "A1",
        "newData": [
            {
                "balance": 100,
            },
            {
                "balance": 200,
            },
            {
                "balance": 300,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "string",
        "label": "A2",
        "newData": [
            {
                "balance": 100,
            },
            {
                "balance": 200,
            },
            {
                "balance": 300,
            }
        ]
    }]
```

Output expected:

```
 totalValueArray = [200,400,600]
```

Comment: Adding that "JSON" didn't help understanding the question *either*. Please actually explain what you are trying to do and how your attempts don't work.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add a question

Comment: @Cid for sure he forgot to add a question xD! Please, explain what you're  aiming for.

Comment: @Chandrashekhar Your JSON is invalid, please use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) to validate that and rectify it. Secondly, how did you come up with the output 200,400,600 .. your JSON seems to have only 2 objects. Please spend some effort to explain yourself clearly, so people here can spend their time to help you.

Comment: my guess is that he wants to sum the first `balance` from the first object with the first `balance` of the second object, and so on... But anyway, he didn't even shown what he tried already and didn't even ask a question

Answer (score 3):

I think i understood what you're doing
you want to sum every index 0 of newData, push it to an array
then move to index 1, index 2...
1 method is with reduce + map, assuming arrayData is what you have

```js
let arrayData = [{
    "id": "string",
    "label": "A1",
    "newData": [
        {
            "balance": 100,
        },
        {
            "balance": 200,
        },
        {
            "balance": 300,
        }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "string",
    "label": "A2",
    "newData": [
        {
            "balance": 100,
        },
        {
            "balance": 200,
        },
        {
            "balance": 300,
        }
    ]
}];
    
let res = arrayData.reduce((acc, elem) => {
  elem.newData.map((n, i) => {
    if (acc[i]) {
      if (acc[i].balance) acc[i] = acc[i].balance + n.balance;
      else acc[i].balance = n.balance;
    } else acc.push(n);
  })
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks Calvin.I understood, I have made mistake in adding questions which is not in correct manner.New to stack-overflow,will take care and never do this again.

Comment: Hi @crm if this answer solves your problem, it's nice to mark it as solved, so, the one who posted the answer earn some points, and if someone is having the same issue than you, he knows this is the good answer :)